# Forcing a git pull, still getting HEAD conflicts though...?

Tags: wordpress, git

Webhost is working fine for my WordPress website. Localhost was the victim of an incomplete WordPress upgrade. I'm trying to get it back online.

I've committed or stashed any local changes. I want to force a pull of production onto localhost without the headache of a merge or rebase.

This is what i've done so far on localhost...

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Problem is though, my localhost gives me internal server errors since the files have HEAD conflicts in them.

I've forced a pull, i haven't done an rebase or merge. I've double checked on production. No HEAD conflicts. I've checked .gitignore and exclude. Nothing.

I've added folders that may have been uncached.

```
git add --force wp-content/plugins/wordfence/*
```

I'm doing something wrong here. And i've no idea what. I'm not a devOps guy as you can probably tell.

EDIT: If this is a new question, i'll repost. I've forced a pull on the right branch ie. 'main' instead of 'master'. However, now i'm back to the broken WordPress upgrade issues...

Missing html-api/*, missing /blocks/ etc.

Why can't i just clone the entire production server? Without losing wp-config-local.php and other essential localhost files etc?

```
localhost: git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I'm not sure how the working tree can be clean, yet webhost is working and localhost isn't. Especially given that the missing files are in the WordPress directory and not on the Operating System?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/mysite/wp-includes/html-api/class-wp-html-attribute-token.php'
```

Why isn't GIT tracking the includes/ folder?

Comment: Do you have multiples branches ? If you do, make sure you have checkout pour master Branch.

Comment: `git status`? `git diff HEAD`? Are the conflict markers committed per chance? Untracked files with conflict markers? Which files have the conflict markers?

Comment: The issue was with the branch name, i had master instead of main. Git didn't show any error message when i used the wrong branch name.

Comment: i can download the missing WordPress core files no issue. Now though, it's giving me missing woocommerce file and plugin files. I'll be here all day downloading every plugin again.

Comment: You sure this commands works as intended? `git reset --hard origin master`? It should be `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: Thanks @eftshift0 can i just clarify, my main branch is main so it'd be ```git reset --hard origin/main ``` right?

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple mistake here guys.

I used this command incorrectly as I'd assumed it added pages to the staging area hence the -a switch...

```
git commit -am '-a add switch and -m message switch'
```

This doesn't actually add files though, you have to explicitly add the files using the command...

```
git add wp-includes/*
```

This is why the server didn't update properly from webhost to localhost when i did a...

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/main
```